# Is there a Dart idiom for Map.mapValues((value) => newValue) which keeps all keys untouched?

Tags: json, data-structures, dart, json-deserialization

I have written the following small utility function which makes my code easy to read:

```
mapValues(Map map, Function f) => map.map((k, v) => MapEntry(k, f(v)));
```

Here is an example using this function to convert json data as the AngularDart Heros tutorial does it, too:

```
class RouteRefs {
  final Map<String, List<RouteRef>> routesByNetwork;

  RouteRefs(this.routesByNetwork);

  static RouteRefs fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    var rawMap = json["routesByNetwork"] as Map;
    return RouteRefs(mapValues(rawMap, routeRefsFromJson));   // !! here !!
  }

  static Iterable routeRefsFromJson(routeList) {
    return (routeList as List)
        .map((rawRef) => RouteRef.fromJson(rawRef as Map))
        .toList();
  }
}
```

Is there already a standard library or utility library function which does such a thing? If no, is writing this as a top-level function in an utility package (or for a start, to keep it lean) an utility source file a best practice?

And since I copied at all that code here already I might also ask something related: code like in `routeRefsFromJson` has quite a bit of redundancy with similar methods on a lot of other model classes. Is there a better practice yet to have less redundancy without over-abstracting the code?

Answer (score 1):

> Is there already a standard library or utility library function which does such a thing?

Not specifically for this.

> If no, is writing this as a top-level function in an utility package (or for a start, to keep it lean) an utility source file a best practice?

I'd say so, yes. Although I'd rewrite your function as such:

```
Map<K, V2> mapValues<K, V1, V2>(Map<K, V1> map, V2 Function(V1) f) =>
  map.map((k, v) => MapEntry(k, f(v)));
```

> Is there a better practice yet to have less redundancy without over-abstracting the code?

I'd use https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/json_serializable – it handles the duplicative boiler plate for you!